# iis app slow loading on first and second request

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm encountering this weird problem with one IIS Website / app:

The problem is that when i open a web browser on certain devices and access to the app, the FIRST and SECOND requests are EXTREMELY SLOW. It takes up to 30 seconds each to load.

After that everything runs smoothly.

This happens only after opening the web browser on CERTAIN devices.
I'll name the devices that the problem persist on and the ones that doesn't.

Devices with the problem:
Galaxy S 1 (cyanogen Mod 10)
Iphone 4S (stock)
ViewSonic VSD220 (runs android ICS)
Toshiba Laptop (win vista, i dont have the specs in hand)

Devices not showing the problem:
4 PC running win xp
Dell laptop (win 7, i dont have the specs in hand either)

The only common factor I've found is that the problem persist only with this APP on mobile devices.
In the laptop scenario i tried with both network cards (wired and wireless) and the results are the same.

I already tried with 2 different IIS servers and different versions (5.1 and 6.0). In different machines...
Creating a new the application pool on the 6.0 IIS server...
the APP pool recycle timer...

Also this is the only APP i have using .net framework 4.0

any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.  It doesn't load the app into memory until it's accessed.  You may want to try this question over at the Webmaster exchange (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If that app of yours is on Sharepoint and published via IIS, it's a feature of Sharepoint, it compiles .NET apps at first request. Maybe your app too gets compiled at first request, then runs normally.

Comment: what happens when you clear the cache of the PCs does it still load fast?  what happens on the 3rd and 4th requests? Is performance consistent across all devices on the 3rd and 4th requests?

Comment: There are a LOT of things that could be going on that deal with the page structure and artifacts (like large JS libraries) that you are forcing the devices to download as well.  Especially on those phones.

Comment: @MichaelGardner but what would explain that it only happens on certain devices and web browsers on those devices?

Comment: @Vesper is not on Sharepoint.

Comment: @RandomUs1r the 3rd+ requests are smooth and fast.

Comment: @ChrisLively i dont quiet understand the JS libraries download thing u said. the devices dont have access to internet :s

Comment: @Gustavo Soto how are they loading your web page if they don't have access to the internet??

Comment: *shrug* that doesn't sound right, mobile phones require data plans from carriers granting them access to 3g/4g aka the internet.  However, your problem's solution lies somewhere between fixing the caching properties of the app, ...without internet if you're trying to access external resources that would cause that 30 second timeout... it could be the way wireless is set up and it just lags since the phones would have to be on the intranet as well, or... if its a server side problem you could try deploying with the pre-compile option on.

Comment: @RandomUs1r bingo! it was the timeout from external resources that was causing the delay. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, just download them locally... like put jQuery.js on your file system and reference it that way.  Also, posted the abstract solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our troubleshooting above, it's determined that some of the app's devices only have LAN connectivity and thus could not access external resources that were referenced in the app.